# How can I convert pdf response to pdf file?

Tags: python, pdf

I'm using [Docraptor](https://docraptor.com/) to convert **HTML to PDF**, docraptor does the conversion and sends me a response, I'm having some trouble understanding how I could convert this response to a PDF file.

Here's what the response looks like :

```
b'%PDF-1.4\n%\xe2\xe3\xcf\xd3\n\n1 0 obj\n<</Type /Catalog\n/Pages 2 0 R>>\nendobj\n\n2 0 obj\n<</Type /Pages\n/Kids [3 0 R]\n/Count 1>>
\nendobj\n\n4 0 obj\n<</Length 5 0 R\n/Filter /FlateDecode>>\nstream\nx\x9cs\n\xe125\xd13\x00\x02\x05s#3=sSC#\x85\x90\x14.}7C\x05C#\x88x
H\x1a\x97\x86GjNN\xbeB\xb8\xa6BH\x16\x97\x89\x81\x9e\x81\x91\xa9\x89\x82\x0  
... ... ... 
... ... lots of code ... ... 
... ... ... 
<</Info 10 0 R\n/Size 11\n/Root 1 0 R\n/ID [<5FCD137048BC4E60BF5E3D2E3741CD4B> <5FCD137048BC4E60BF5E3D2E3741CD4B>]>>\nstartxref\n12234\n
%%EOF\n'
```

---

I was thinking to do something like that :

```
#docraptor response
response = doc_api.create_doc({ "type": "pdf", "document_content": "<html><body>Hello World!</body></html>" }) 

with open("test.pdf", "wb") as f:
    f.write(response)

file = open(f.name, 'r').read()
```

> **Error:** UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x90 in position 195: character maps to

How can I achieve this ?

Comment: Where does the error occur? You may also need the flags `rb` when reading, if it occurs there.

Comment: @KenSyme Yes, this time no error occurs but `file` is not under file format, it's still the same code as `response`, how can I put it into a downloadable file ?

Comment: Well it's now saved on disk as a pdf - what do you want to do with it?

Comment: @KenSyme I want to make a downloadable link with it

Comment: Do download from where to where? Have you got a web server running?

Comment: @KenSyme Yes I'm using django, and I don't know what I should return to my html

Comment: I would ask a new question - mhawke has answered the problem of the error message, ask another question (or have a search) about serving a pdf  file through django.

Comment: @KenSyme Yes you're right, I'll do that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use binary mode when opening the file for reading:

```
with open('test.pdf', 'rb') as f:
    doc = f.read()
```

Without the binary flag Python 3 expects that the data is encoded with the default file system encoding, and it will attempt to decode the incoming data into a unicode string:

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.getfilesystemencoding()
'utf-8'
```

On my system the default encoding is UTF-8. When in text mode Python will try to decode from UTF8 into a `str` object, but that might fail if the data in the file is not UTF-8 encoded.

Comment: I know this is kind of out of scope, but `doc` is exactly the same as `response` (returns the same string), how should I do if I want it to be a downloadable link ? what should I return to my html ?

Comment: @Lindow DocRaptor asynchronous documents only returns binary files, not links. To make it a link, you'll need to save the binary file to your server somewhere and provide that link to your users.